Solve coupled ODEs analytically in the limit of a small parameter
I have the following set of coupled second order non-linear ODEs :
$$ x^2 a''(x) + x  a'(x) - \Big(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\Big)b^2(x) a(x) = 0 \\ 
x b''(x) -  b'(x) - 2x b(x)a^2(x) = 0$$
with boundary conditions :
$$ a(0) = 0 ~~~~~~ b(0) = 1 ~~~~~~~~ a(\infty) = 1 ~~~~~~~~ b(\infty) =0  $$
The domain is $[0,\infty)$ ; $a,b$ are real functions.  I want to try and solve these equations in the limit of small $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$.
My initial approach is through boundary layer analysis or a wkb analysis. However I have been unable to isolate the correct terms properly for the 'inner' and 'outer' regions in the analysis (and how to define these regions correctly).
Any help in understanding these equations would be greatly appreciated.

What does it mean to solve an ODE in a limit?

@user479223 I'm essentially interested in knowing the behavior of $a,b$ at $\epsilon = 0$. Perhaps do perturbation theory around this solution in small $\epsilon$

When $\epsilon=0$ the first equation is not well defined.

Yes, I understand explicitly at $\epsilon=0$, it is not well defined. However,  since the domain is $[0,\infty)$, potentially terms on the lhs can compete with the $1/\epsilon$ term on the rhs. I wanted to see if for a small positive $\epsilon \neq 0 $, I can study $a,b$ analytically.

Maybe these are not the best words but I want to ask the following. If I wish to do perturbation theory, for a system of odes (dependent on a parameter $\epsilon$), in some small parameter $\epsilon$, then is there a way to study this system, even though the explicit unperturbed system ($\epsilon=0$) is not well defined at face value ?

If you multiply the first equation by $\epsilon^2$, then it's well defined in the limit but you have a singular perturbation and in the limit you have a differential algebraic system.  This is a topic covered in many textbooks.
